# a stable way to check domain availability with pywhois

Tags: python, pywhois

I use this code to check domain availability:

```
try:
    w = pywhois.whois('honarasai.com')
    if not w:
        message='Domain is available'
except:
    message='Domain is taken'
```

It returns this result:

```
creation_date: ['11-jun-2012'] domain_name: ['HONARASAI.COM', 'honarasai.com'] emails: ['domain@netafraz.com', 'domain@netafraz.com', 'domain@netafraz.com', 'domain@netafraz.com'] expiration_date: ['11-jun-2013'] name_servers: ['NS.HONARASAI.COM', 'NS2.HONARASAI.COM'] referral_url: ['http://www.OnlineNIC.com'] registrar: ['ONLINENIC, INC.'] status: ['clientTransferProhibited'] updated_date: ['11-jun-2012'] whois_server: ['whois.onlinenic.com']
```

When internet speed is low it doesn't work stable and return wrong result. What is an accurate way to check the result to get a stable response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"internet speed is low" certainly means your request times out. You can catch that by specifying an exception on your `except` line:

`except socket.timeout:`

If you catch such an exception, you'll have to retry your request again later.

Comment: except socket.timeout doesn't catch this exception and when request takes a long time,the process continue til raise an error!

Comment: Well, what exception does it raise, then?